# What is the most efficient way to upload multiple images to Cloudinary in a single request using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I want to upload multiple images at once, I'm using cloudinary and currently I'm able to upload multiple images on cloudinary but I think this is not the good aproach because I'm making separate request each time for each single image. I've checked similar answeres on community but none of these works.

```
  const vehicleIcon = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.vehicleIcon.tempFilePath,
    {
      public_id: `${brand} ${name} icon`,
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "Vehicles",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.vehicleIcon.tempFilePath);
  const frontImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.frontImage.tempFilePath,
    {
      public_id: `${brand} ${name} front image`,
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "Vehicles",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.frontImage.tempFilePath);
  const backImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.backImage.tempFilePath,
    {
      public_id: `${brand} ${name} back image`,
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "Vehicles",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.backImage.tempFilePath);
  const sideImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.sideImage.tempFilePath,
    {
      public_id: `${brand} ${name} side image`,
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "Vehicles",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.sideImage.tempFilePath);
  const interiorImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.interiorImage.tempFilePath,
    {
      public_id: `${brand} ${name} interior image`,
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "Vehicles",
    }
  );
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files.interiorImage.tempFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Cloudinary for quite a while now and have had a similar query to yours concerning bulk uploads. Till where I know, you cannot upload several assets to Cloudinary with a single request. But you can improve your current code using a loop to avoid code repetition.

If you have all the images you want to upload in one directory, you can run this Node.js code:

```
// Import packages
const fs = require('fs');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

// Replace with your credentials to configure Cloudinary
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: "cloud",
  api_key: "key",
  api_secret: "secret"
});

// Function to upload multiple images
const uploadMultipleImages = async (directoryPath, batchID) => {
  try {
    const fileNames = await fs.promises.readdir(directoryPath); // Read the file names from the specified directory

    const uploadResults = await Promise.all(
      fileNames.map(async (fileName) => {
        const imagePath = `${directoryPath}/${fileName}`; // Build the full path of each image file
        return cloudinary.uploader.upload(imagePath, {
          use_filename: true,
          tags: `batch ${batchID}` // Add a tag to identify the batch of uploaded images
        });
      })
    );

    // Process the upload results
    uploadResults.forEach((result) => {
      console.log(`Image uploaded with public ID: ${result.public_id}`);
      console.log(`Image URL: ${result.secure_url}`);
      console.log('----------------------');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
};

// Usage example
const directoryPath = 'asset_directory';
const batchID = 1;
uploadMultipleImages(directoryPath, batchID);
```

As done in the code above, I feel it is always helpful to tag a group of uploads with a batch number for easier tracking in the Cloudinary Media Library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to upload images in bulk, but I've found an suitable way to avoid code repeat.

Here, all you need to create an function, it is suitable to save in other file and then import

```
const uploadImage = async (req, id, folder, title) => {
  const image = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files[id].tempFilePath, {
    public_id: `${title}`,
    use_filename: true,
    folder: `${folder}`,
  });
  fs.unlinkSync(req.files[id].tempFilePath);
  return image;
};
```

whenever you want to upload an image just call the function and give a name to the function because you need an URL of image

```
  const thumbnail = await uploadImage(
    req,
    "thumbnail",
    "Vehicles",
    `Vehicle thumbnail`
  );
```

you can access the image link as below

```
 thumbnail = thumbnail.secure_url;
```